# ImportError: No module named werkzeug.utils

Tags: python, odoo

I have downloaded odoo9 source code from `https://www.github.com/odoo/odoo --depth 1 --branch 9.0 --single-branch .`
 and started the odoo server but i see "ImportError: No module named werkzeug.utils" error.

I tried installing with 
`sudo apt-get install -y python3-werkzeug` and could see it is installed successfully.

Again when I run the server I still see the same import issue.
how could I fix this import errors when I already installed them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Odoo 9.0 is no longer supported since long ago, and it only works with Python 2, so you'd have to install `python2-werkzeug` instead (if available).

Only Odoo 11.0 and newer run under Python 3.

Comment: i get ```E: Unable to locate package python2-werkzeug``` when I give python2-werkzeug

Comment: I have pulled the sourcecode for odoo 11.0 and i still have the python version 2.7 and how can i update it to 3.x version?